# Creating a hierarchical menu in Vaadin 23

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I returned to the Vaadin ecosystem after some years out and I can't find the good old Tree component for creating a left navigational menu hierarchies in Vaadin 23.

What I found is a TreeGrid, however, it is explicitly stated in the docs, that it is not intended for that use case: "Tree Grid is not meant to be used as a navigation menu."

In the docs for Tree from the V8 we see that the Tree was intended for menus: "A typical use of the Tree component is for displaying a hierarchical menu".

So it seems now there is a gap - there is no dedicated component in Vaadin for hierarchical menus. How to fill this gap in Vaadin 23?

Comment: What is your use case? The old tree menu was not optimal from an accesibility point of view

Comment: https://start.vaadin.com/app has a new AppNav example since last week. This can be used to build hierarchical navigation. Check it out

Comment: @AndréSchild the basic use case is quite simple, it uses 3-4 level hierarchies: there are a number of regions, in each region there are a number of company deployments, each of which has departments and in some cases subdepartments. Click on each tree item displayed statistics and editing capabilities for the selected hierarchy item in the right panel. With Tree it was modelled and displayed very naturally.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli didn't found. I login but couldn't find the AppNav from the template list

Comment: Just create a new application and you'll find it in the AppLayout

Comment: @SimonMartinelli created new app. In the layout I see only: "Side menu", "Top menu", "No menu"

Comment: @Kivan it's not visible in the builder, see the finished product. There's the AppNavItem class which is used to construct the menu, which you can also use to create a hierarchy.

Comment: [Documentation](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.8.14/com/vaadin/flow/component/treegrid/TreeGrid.html) states only "A grid component for displaying hierarchical tabular data." There is nothing about not using it for navigation. Where did you find that quote?

Comment: @Eisenknurr in the Best Practices section of Tree Grid

Comment: @ollitietavainen thx, I found what you have mentioned in the test project, It works. But  how to make the whole tree expanded/collapsed? V8 tree had such kind of option

Comment: @ollitietavainen and one more question, it's working fine with static routing, but what about dynamic routing, where menu items are generated based on data?